# Was there once a semi-serious space-art project planning to use solar reflectors to put a spot of light on the crescent Moon?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art

Reading the question [What are the effects of orbital reflectors and advertising on scientific observation and orbital debris?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/33758/12102) I am reminded of a story I read a while ago about an even in the past, perhaps 10 years ago but it could be even longer.

I believe the story was described in a blog post by an astronomer, or a science historian.

There was a "space art" project being discussed by some combination of astronomers, engineers, and artists.

An installation of large flat mirrors, like that of a solar furnace or  thermal power generating station would all be pointed such that they would reflect toward a single point on the dark, unlit part of a crescent moon. People one or two time-zones to the East would see a spot lit up on the crescent moon just after sunset.

I can not find any trace of this story now, but from what I read, after the numbers were crunched, it was do-able.

Then the death threats came, and the project was put aside.

Has anyone else heard of this plan, or read of it, or can find a link where to read about it?

[image]

[Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMWIgwvbrcM)

Comment: https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes, it seems there was!

I found the podcast I was thinking of, but the mystery deepens further. It was the first of two in-depth discussions between Mary Lou Jepsen and Rob Reid of Ars Technica; these are worth a thorough listen:

- [Ars Technicast Experimental #3.1: Rob Reid and Mary Lou Jepsen, 1 of 2](https://player.fm/series/the-ars-technicast/ars-technicast-experimental-31-rob-reid-and-mary-lou-jepsen-1-of-2) The bit about projecting video on the Moon is at about `06:00`
- [Ars Technicast Experimental #3.2: Rob Reid and Mary Lou Jepsen, 2 of 2](https://player.fm/series/the-ars-technicast/ars-technicast-experimental-32-rob-reid-and-mary-lou-jepsen-2-of-2) Peter Gabriel saves us from Facebook

Her accolades in optics abound, which suggests that she already knew how get around issues described in @BobJacobsen's [convincing answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33776/12102).

Her TED page: https://www.ted.com/speakers/mary_lou_jepsen

Her profile in Forbes: [How This Former MIT Professor And Google Engineer Used Holograms To Build A \$28 Million Startup](https://www.forbes.com/sites/laurenaratani/2018/11/29/how-holograms-and-a-brain-tumor-led-to-success-for-mary-lou-jepsen-serial-entrepreneur-and-former-google-facebook-and-intel-manager/#1e36369830ff)

Her web site: https://www.maryloujepsen.com/

> Dr. Mary Lou Jepsen is the founder of [Openwater](http://www.openwater.cc/) whose goal is to see deep into the body with the detail of a high resolution 3D camera.  The implications are broad for both healthcare and for communication directly with thought .  Previously she was an engineering executive at Facebook, Oculus, Google[x] and Intel as well as a founder of 4 startups including One Laptop per Child where she was CTO, chief architect and delivered to mass production the \$100 laptop.  Her startup CEO experience includes the world’s only fabless display screen company which was based in Taipei. She has been a professor at MIT and is an inventor on over 100 published or issued patents in the last 5 years alone. She has been recognized with many awards including TIME magazine’s “Time 100” as one of the 100 most influential people in the world and as a CNN top 10 thinker.

More talks on technology at OpenWater: https://www.openwater.cc/technology

---

From Floating Times's [Issaquah Inventor Mary Lou Jepsen](https://ft.floatinghomes.org/issaquah-inventor-mary-lou-jepsen/);

[image: Issaquah Inventor Mary Lou Jepsen]

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Thanks for the edit! After seeing your profile I thought you might be interested in [Is it common and good engineering for a pair of cables to be easily plugged into each other's connectors in modern spacecraft, or](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48580/12102)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I definitely am *very* interested.

Answer (score 6):

It would require a *really* big installation, which would be monumental art all on its own.

The Sun’s light has about a 10mrad divergence due to the non-zero size of the sun. Redirecting sunlight back to the Moon with passive optics (I.e. a mirror) makes a spot that’s basically the size of the Moon (the Sun and Moon have the same angular diameter from Earth)

To make a smaller spot, you have to collimate the beam and throw power away. But that doesn’t make the resulting beam, nor spot on the Moon any brighter; just smaller.

So, to make a spot on the moon that’s e.g. 10% as bright with *passive* *solar* *reflectors*, probably just about visible against the sunlit side, you’d need 10% of the visible area of the Moon in reflectors, or about 1 million km2. An art installation fully covering an area 1000 km on a side would really cool...

Comment: This makes the my interest in finding the answer to the question (if there is one) all the more compelling to find, because it sounded convincing at the time I read it, and yet now it seems that [conservation of etendue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue) makes a strong argument against making a small spot on the moon at least in the way I've described from memory...

Comment: I found the podcast! https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34729/12102

Comment: The proposal is to put a spot on the *unlit* face of the moon, which would need orders of magnitude less light flux to be visible.

Comment: The question is about the crescent moon.  10:1 dynamic range on something that small is probably ok; I’d be surprised if 1:100 is visible,  but perhaps. The lit moon is about $10^4$ brighter than the unlit part (about 10 magnitudes) so even a small crescent, a couple percent lit, will dominate the field.