# How big will a space billboard have to be to be visible?

Tags: low-earth-orbit, commercial

So recently there's been the [news story](https://futurism.com/the-byte/spacex-billboard-ads-space) about how SpaceX is launching a billboard to space (space billboards are an approximately [bi-annual occurrence](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/what-are-the-effects-of-orbital-reflectors-and-advertising-on-scientific-observa)). This "billboard" is a cubesat that will just display ads on a livestream of Earth, similar to what NASA was doing with [HDEV](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/explorer/Investigation.html?#id=892). However, what people are imagining is a billboard, visible from orbit on the ground.

Ignoring the fact it's already [illegal](https://twitter.com/DJSnM/status/1424740079134679045), to do what they're imagining feels to me like a borderline physical impossible, simply because of how big the billboard would have to be; the ISS is basically a point source and it's the size of a [football field](https://www.justintools.com/unit-conversion/length.php?k1=football-field-length-%5BUS%5D&k2=nanometers). Writing out even just visible plain text feels like it would be hard.

So how big would a space billboard have to be? (and is it reasonably possible to construct one?)

Comment: As a suggestion, read [*Watch this Space* from Arthur C. Clarke's *Venture to the Moon* from 1956.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venture_to_the_Moon)  You wouldn't build a physical billboard.  It'd be cheaper and easier to "skywrite" the advertisement.

Comment: I think a fleet of satellites flying in (relative) formation that can maneuver to be the 'pixels' of an image is way more practical than one big satellite

Comment: What about a bunch of tiny cubesats and launch them from a parent vessel in such a way that they reenter together, and for a brief moment produce a corporate logo as they burn up? If they are made out of different materials you could even possibly have a bit of color in the logo

Comment: @Innovine You mean like this/ https://spaceflightnow.com/2019/11/28/japanese-company-to-launch-artificial-meteor-shower-satellite/

Comment: @pcman wow, yes, exactly that :) they didn't mention using it for adverts, but the project name Sky Canvas is a bit of a giveaway :)

Comment: The cartoonist [André Franquin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Franquin) had his own bet in the story "[Z is for Zorglub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_comme_Zorglub)". [![zorglub ad on moon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jaWt.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jaWt.jpg)

Comment: **Don't give Richard Branson any more ideas!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose we start with [@SE-stopfiringthegoodguys's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/54541/12102) of 1000 km orbit but instead of making it solid and darkly and diffusely reflective like the Moon (albedo only 0.15-ish)

[image: moon photobombs earth] [image: Buzz Aldrin carries the EASEP]

what if it produced its own light like a billboard?

For reference, the full moon is about magnitude -13 and the earthshine from the part we can see via reflected light from Earth [is about magnitude -3](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/281146827_Apparent_magnitude_of_earthshine_A_simple_calculation/link/58aae625a6fdcc0e079a0576/download).

But not to be outdone by the Moon let's stick with a brightness of -13.

Per [How to make a green LED as visually bright as a 0 magnitude star?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282106/83380) in Physics SE, I got that an object that appeared to be 0 magnitude in green light should illuminate the Earth with about  $2.1 \times10^{-9} \ W/m^2$.

> If it is roughly uniform over a cone with a half-width of 10°, then the LED produces $ 0.7 \ W/Sr$, or  $ 0.7/r^2 \ W/m^2$ at a distance of $r$ meters.
>
> That means I would have to move my 100 mA, 30% eQE 555nm LED with a 10° half-angle 18 kilometers away for it to look roughly as bright a 0 visual magnitude star!

For color dependence and an independent check, see also:

- [How can I estimate the optical power that a single-color LED generates?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/325949/102305)

At a bias of say 3 volts, our LED needs 0.3 watts to be 0 magnitude at 18 km with a half-angle of 10°.

To be -13 mag at 1000 km over a 30° half-angle would then need about 500 megawatts.

It's hard to compete with astronomical objects. Stick with shiny things if you want a big solid billboard.

But if you can live with "a thousand points of light" then consider a group of LED-bearing cubesats.

At 450 km each satellite can shine as a 0 magnitude star over a 10° half-angle using only 7.5 watts which is a perfectly reasonable power load for a well designed and built 3U cubesat with solar panels and batteries to maintain much of the time.

If your "flock" of cubesats can communicate with each other or better yet see each other, then they can "fly" in formation like an LED drone show, which has a lot of pluses over a flat, static and boring billboard.

[image: Screenshot from Biggest drone display ever! - Guinness World Records https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44KvHwRHb3A] [image: Screenshot from Biggest drone display ever! - Guinness World Records https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44KvHwRHb3A]

Screenshots from [Biggest drone display ever! - Guinness World Records](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44KvHwRHb3A) (click for larger)

---

From [Have any satellites had lights visible from Earth besides FITSat-1?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/40534/12102)

[image: FITSAT-1]

[image: FITSAT-1]

Comment: Even those large half-angles, at an altitude of 1000km, are only enough to be seen from small areas of the surface, so to cover all of Europe or all of the US would need another the equivalent of a few large power stations in orbit

Comment: @ChrisH that's precisely the point of that section, and the reason I proposed the alternative "thousand points of light" 0 magnitude star-like cubesat constellation. Envelope-back calculation suggests only about 7 watts average power for a 10° half-angle. There is room for optimization, but it's still going to be a lot less glamorous than a 9 kilometer wide billboard, and a lot more achievable near term.

Comment: Yes, after running the numbers because the angles felt too big, I felt a footnote was in order

Comment: Why bother powering LEDs? Why not just reflect sunlight, like the ISS or some of the SpaceX sats do?

Comment: @jcaron it's a good question and if you post it as such there will probably be a few answers since there have been many attempts.

Answer (score 4):

An object already in the sky that clearly has a cultural impact is the Moon. We can use it as a benchmark for how large a space billboard has to be.

While the angular diameter of the Moon isn't too large, it is enough to make out some details, so a billboard of similar apparent size would be sufficient for displaying a logo, which I would say is enough to be an efficient advertisement if well designed.

To avoid atmospheric drag, the billboard probably has to be as high as a 1000km orbit, which would place it 384 times closer than the Moon, and thus require a diameter 384 times smaller, **9km wide**.

This would rule out pretty much any construction method that requires a non-trivial thickness. What's left then are foils.

With tested solar sail materials, that's at least 250-500 tonnes for just the foil alone, neglecting any support structure. This could perhaps be reduced slightly by using holes and voids in the foil as part of the logo design, but this would nevertheless be one of the largest construction projects ever undertaken in space.

Comment: I fully expect a large faceless multinational corporation to fund it anyway.

Comment: I suppose you could imagine a smaller billboard in a lower orbit as well.  The higher drag would mean that it wouldn't stay up as long, but it would be cheaper.  And I could imagine that a Space Billboard™ would lose its effectiveness as an advertising gimmick once everyone had got used to its existence.  ("Hey, remember that orbiting Pepsi logo they put up a few years back?  Did you know that you can still see it at night?")

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yeah, but if you keep making it smaller and closer, at some point, it's just a blimp, or a plane with a banner behind it - we already have those...

Comment: If you drop it down to a 250-km orbit, it only needs to be 2.25 km across, with a mass of 15-30 tonnes.  A Falcon Heavy could launch a pair of those billboards into low Earth orbit.

Comment: @Mark the problems with such a low orbit are numerous. In addition to the huge atmospheric drag that something so large would experience (it would probably reenter the atmosphere in a few hours or days due to it's enormous cross-sectional area) and the atomic oxygen at that altitude would eat the paint off. At such a low altitude the visibility would only be from a very narrow path, the time visible would be shorter (but still maybe a minute or so) and the window for it being still sunlit while it's simultaneously dark on the ground would be very narrow near dusk/dawn.

Comment: @Mark the great expense of deploying a kilometer-size object along with it's very short life and very few chances for people to see it makes VLO (very low orbit) not a good choice for advertising to a large audience. However, as a stunt for a particular audience (e.g. a billionaire's birthday wish) it would certainly work nicely! See also [How much do on-demand, artificial meteor showers cost these days?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46186/12102)

Comment: @uhoh, the cost of 30 seconds of advertising time on the Super Bowl broadcast is around $5 million.  I'm sure there are plenty of companies that would be willing to pay five times that for an orbital ad.

Comment: @Mark that carries with it a guaranteed huge audience. The orbital mechanics makes it hard to do it here, as does the timing (everyone has to suddenly go outside and look up at the same time, just after sunset, the weather has to be good, the sky clear, etc.) It will be a challenge.